How to Create a Shadow in SwiftUI Only at bottom
I'm trying to create a shadow effect in SwiftUI that only appears beneath the lower half of a rectangle.
Current Code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle() 
            .fill(Color.blue) // Fill the rectangle with blue color
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100) // Set the rectangle's dimensions
            .shadow(radius: 10) // This applies shadow to the entire rectangle
    }
}

Problem:
In the code above, the shadow is applied to the entire rectangle. However, I only want the shadow to show beneath the lower half of the rectangle.

What exactly is your question? Please have a look at [ask].

@BenzyNeez Not sure that would work, since clipShape will likely include the shadow. You should provide an answer with actual code if there is way to make it work as you suggested.

@BenzyNeez I just added an answer. I'd be curious to see an alternative with clipShape as you mentioned, if this is the effect intended.

You need to add the shadow as an overlay so it can be offset and then mask it.
struct BottomShadow: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                Color.blue
                    .shadow(radius: 5, y: 5)
                    .mask{
                        Color.black
                            .offset(y: 15)
                    }
            }
   
        Spacer()
    }
}

#Preview {
    BottomShadow()
}

Resulting in this:

If you play with the size of the overlay, the values and order of the modifiers, you can also get creative:
Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(height: 5)
                    .mask{
                        Color.black
                            // .offset(y: 5)
                            // .padding(.top, 3) // <- modifiers here can be used for additional control
                    }
                    .shadow(radius: 3, y: 10)
            }

This will give a shadow that can be somewhat in the air, but also slightly extends to the sides, rather than be clipped like the previous one.


Thanks for pointing that out. It was meant for some placeholders. I updated the answer to this effect. BTW, I did try with clipShape initially, but I couldn't get this result. So I am intrigued if there is a more efficient way using clipShape to achieve this.

Ah you got me, I've been talking about clip shape but actually meant mask all along. They're kind of similar, but mask is a lot more flexible. My bad, sorry.

Makes sense, no worries

Makes sense, no worries

@AndreiG. thx it was excel what I needed!

Happy to hear. Can you mark it as a solution if it's what you were looking for then? Thanks.

@AndreiG. I have edit the question, can you have a second look ?

@Moran You didn't just edit the question, you changed the question entirely and now the solution provided no longer makes sense. This is not an acceptable practice. You should revert the edits and accept my previous solution if it answered your initial question. Then, create a new question with the new problem and code.
